# Handling multibyte (non-ASCII) characters in C

Tags: c, string, file, character

I am trying to do my own version of wc (unix filter), but I have a problem with non-ASCII characters. I did a HEX dump of a text file and found out that these characters occupy more than one byte. So they won't fit to char. Is there any way I can read these characters from file and handle them like single characters (in order to count characters in a file) in C?
I've been googling a little bit and found some wchar_t type, but there were not any simple examples how to use it with files.

Comment: You're going to need to know about Unicode and in particular encodings. Do you currently know what these terms mean?

Comment: Also, you may want to know about non-ASCII single byte encodings, such as the various ISO encodings, Windows 1252 etc. As you may know, ASCII is actually a 7 bit wide encoding.

Comment: @Joey thanks, so used to ASCII, ISO, ANSI etc. I formed a bad habit!

Answer (score 9):

> I've been googling a little bit and found some wchar_t type, but there was not any simple example how to use it with files.

Well met.  There weren't any simple examples because, unfortunately, proper character set support **isn't simple**.

*Aside:  In an ideal world, everybody would use UTF-8 (a Unicode encoding that is memory-efficient, robust, and backward-compatible with ASCII), the standard C library would include UTF-8 encoding-decoding support, and the answer to this question (and dealing with text in general) would be simple and straightforward.*

The answer to the question "[What is the best unicode library for C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114611/what-is-the-best-unicode-library-for-c)" is to use the [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) library.  You may want to look at [ustdio.h](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ustdio_8h.html), as it has a [`u_fgetc`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ustdio_8h.html#afbed21b23ad994d4c4f83e4fe3e8a890) function, and adding Unicode support to your program will probably take little more than typing `u_` a few times.

Also, if you can spare a few minutes for some light reading, you may want to read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know about Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) from Joel On Software.

I, personally, have never used ICU, but I probably will from now on :-)

Comment: I really liked your: "The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know about Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)". Great post!.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to write a standard C version of the `wc` utility that respects the current language setting when it is run, then you can indeed use the `wchar_t` versions of the stdio functions.  At program startup, you should call `setlocale()`:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
```

This will cause the wide character functions to use the appropriate character set defined by the environment - eg. on Unix-like systems, the `LANG` environment variable.  For example, this means that if your `LANG` variable is set to a `UTF8` locale, the wide character functions will handle input and output in UTF8.  (This is how the POSIX `wc` utility is specified to work).

You can then use the wide-character versions of all the standard functions.  For example, if you have code like this:

```
long words = 0;
int in_word = 0;
int c;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    if (isspace(c))
    {
        if (in_word)
        {
            in_word = 0;
            words++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        in_word = 1;
    }
}
```

...you would convert it to the wide character version by changing `c` to a `wint_t`, `getchar()` to `getwchar()`, `EOF` to `WEOF` and `isspace()` to `iswspace()`:

```
long words = 0;
int in_word = 0;
wint_t c;

while ((c = getwchar()) != WEOF)
{
    if (iswspace(c))
    {
        if (in_word)
        {
            in_word = 0;
            words++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        in_word = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is discourteous to downvote without an explanatory comment.

Answer (score 2):

Go have a look at [ICU](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/). That library is what you need to deal with all the issues.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers so far have merit, but which you use depends on the semantics you want:

- If you want to process text in the configured locale's encoding, and don't care about complete failure in the case of encountering invalid sequences, using `getwchar()` is fine.
- If you want to process text in the configured locale's encoding, but need to detect and recover from invalid sequences, you need to read bytes and use `mbrtowc` manually.
- If you always want to process text as UTF-8, you need to read bytes and feed them to your own decoder. If you know in advance the file will be valid UTF-8, you can just count bytes in the ranges `00-7F` and `C2-F4` and skip counting all other bytes, but this could give wrong results in the presence of invalid sequences. A more robust approach would be decoding the bytestream to Unicode codepoints and counting the number of successful decodes.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you really need the number of **characters**?  `wc` counts the number of **bytes**.

```
~$ echo 'דניאל' > hebrew.txt
~$ wc hebrew.txt 
 1  1 11 hebrew.txt
```

(11 = 5 two-byte characters + 1 byte for '\n')

However, if you really do want to count characters rather than bytes, and can assume that your text files are encoded in UTF-8, then the easiest approach is to count all bytes that are *not* trail bytes (i.e., in the range 0x80 to 0xBF).

If you *can't* assume UTF-8 but *can* assume that any non-UTF-8 files are in a single-byte encoding, then perform a UTF-8 validation check on the data.  If it passes, return the number of UTF-8 lead bytes.  If if fails, return the number of total bytes.

(Note that the above approach is specific to `wc`.  If you're actually *doing* something with the characters rather than just counting them, you'll need to know the encoding.)

Comment: Note that `wc -m` does indeed count *characters* as opposed to *bytes* - `wc -m hebrew.txt` gives the output `6 hebrew.txt` .