# c reading non ASCII characters

Tags: c, text, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters

I am parsing a file that involves characters such as **æ** **ø** **å**. If we assume I have stored a line of the text file as follows

```
#define MAXLINESIZE 1024
char* buffer = malloc(MAXLINESIZE)
...
fgets(buffer,MAXLINESIZE,handle)
...
```

if I wanted to *count* the number of characters on a line. If I try to do the following:

```
char* p = buffer
int count = 0;
while (*p != '\n') {
    if (isgraph(*p)) {
        count++;
    }
    p++;
}
```

this ignores the any occurrence of **æ** **ø** **å**

ie: counting "aåeæioøu" would return 5 not 8

do I need to read the file in an alternative way? should I not be using a `char*` but an `int*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand which encoding is used for your characters. I guess it is very probably [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) (and you should use [UTF8 everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/)....), read [Joel's blog on Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). If your encoding is not UTF-8 you should convert it to UTF-8 e.g. using [libiconv](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/).

Then you need a C library for UTF-8. There are many of them (but none is standardized in the [C11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) language yet). I recommend [libunistring](http://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/) or [glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Unicode-Manipulation.html) (from GTK), but see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4589135/841108).

Your code will change, since an UTF-8 character can take one to four [8 bits] bytes (but Wikipedia [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) page mentions 6 bytes at most; See [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/) standards for details). You won't test if a byte (i.e. a plain C `char`) is a letter, but if a byte and the few bytes after it (given by a pointer, i.e. a `char*` or better by `uint8_t*`) encode a letter (including cyrillic letters, etc..).

Not every sequence of bytes is a valid UTF-8 representation, and you might want to *validate* a line (or a null-terminated C string) before analyzing it.

Comment: The maximum number of bytes needed to represent a Unicode code point in UTF-8 is 4, regardless of what older documents suggest.  The last Unicode value is U+10FFFF.  Once upon a decade or more ago, the upper bound was not defined.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you use UTF-8.

You need to understand [how UTF-8 works](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/utf8.htm).

Here's a little piece of work which should do what you want :

```
int nbChars(char *str) {
    int len = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int charSize = 0; // Size of the current char in byte

    if (!str)
        return -1;
    while (str[i])
    {
        if (charSize == 0)
        {
            ++len;
            if (!(str[i] >> 7 & 1)) // ascii char
                charSize = 1;
            else if (!(str[i] >> 5 & 1))
                charSize = 2;
            else if (!(str[i] >> 4 & 1))
                charSize = 3;
            else if (!(str[i] >> 3 & 1))
                charSize = 4;
            else
                return -1; // not supposed to happen
        }
        else if (str[i] >> 6 & 3 != 2)
            return -1;
        --charSize;
        ++i;
    }
    return len;
}
```

It returns the number of chars, and -1 if it's not a valid UTF-8 string.

(By non-valid UTF-8 string, I mean the format is not valid. I don't check if the character actually exists)

**EDIT: As stated in the comment section, this code doesn't handle decomposed unicode**

Comment: This is a good illustration of why you really need to use a library.  The above code will not necessarily count the number of characters properly because some characters can be encoded in more than one way e.g. å might be encoded as  the single character `C3 A5` in UTF-8 or it might be encoded as an a followed by ˚ i.e. `61 CB 9A`.  The two forms are called composed and decomposed Unicode respectively.

Answer (score 2):

The C standard IO library can only read *bytes*. Your file probably contains multibyte characters, encoded with UTF8 or some other encoding. You'll need a library for interpreting such files.

It is possible that your file contains Latin1 text, in which case characters are bytes. In this case, you cannot use `isgraph` unless you have the proper locale set.

*Bottom line:* find the encoding used in your file. Then read it accordingly. In any case, plain C does not know about encodings.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588897/handling-multibyte-non-ascii-characters-in-c.